# Change the value true/false to Active/inactive of the @nameof(MiddlewareModel.Active)

Tags: c#, telerik, blazor-webassembly, telerik-grid

On other occasions I have been able to solve this problem using ternaries with the difference that it was within html code as shown below:
`<td>@(InfoMiddleware.Active ? "Active" : "Disable")</td>`

The detail is that now I use Telerik components and within it it does not let me use the ternary since the error thrown is "The expression does not have a name".

I need this table to show the active/disable status..
[image]

The code you used makes use of telerik:
**Error:**
[image]
`

```
@if (middlewareHeader == null)
{
    <div class="alert alert-success w-100">
        <p><i class="fas fa-spin fa-spinner"></i> The middlewares is loading...</p>
    </div>
}
else
{
    @switch (isSelected)
    {
        case true:
            <TelerikGrid Data="middlewareHeader" Sortable="true" Pageable="true" FilterMode="GridFilterMode.FilterMenu">
                <GridToolBar>
                    <GridSearchBox Placeholder="@Placeholder"
                       Width="@(SearchBoxWidth >= 100 ? SearchBoxWidth +"px" : "100px")"
                       DebounceDelay="@DebounceDelay">
                    </GridSearchBox>
                </GridToolBar>
                <GridColumns>
                    <GridColumn Field="@nameof(MiddlewareModel.MiddlewareId)"
                    Title="Middleware"></GridColumn>
                    <GridColumn Field="@nameof(MiddlewareModel.Description)"
                    Title="Description"></GridColumn>
                    <GridColumn Field="@nameof(MiddlewareModel.Active ? "Active" : "Disable")"
                    Title="Status"></GridColumn>
                    <GridColumn Field="@nameof(MiddlewareModel.MiddlewareId)" 
                    Title="Navigation">
                        <Template>
                            <TelerikButton @onclick="@(() => Navigation.NavigateTo($"/Environments/{environmentId}/Middlewares/{(context as MiddlewareModel).MiddlewareId}"))">More Information</TelerikButton>
                        </Template>
                    </GridColumn>
                </GridColumns>
            </TelerikGrid>
            break;
        case false:
            <div class="container">
                @foreach (var middleware in middlewareHeader)
                {
                    <CardMiddleware MiddlewareId="@middleware.MiddlewareId"
                    Description="@middleware.Description"
                    Active="@middleware.Active"
                    url="@($"/Environments/{environmentId}/Middlewares/{middleware.MiddlewareId}")">
                    </CardMiddleware>
                }
            </div>
            break;
    }
}

@code {
    private MiddlewareModel[]? middlewareHeader;

    [Parameter]
    public string? environmentId { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public string? middlewareId { get; set; }

    private bool isSelected { get; set; }

    string Placeholder { get; set; } = "Search by Middleware...";
    int? SearchBoxWidth { get; set; } = 200;
    int DebounceDelay { get; set; } = 200;

    public IEnumerable<BreadcrumbItem> Items = new List<BreadcrumbItem>();

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        var baseUrl = "https://localhost:7246/";
        Items = new List<BreadcrumbItem>
        {
            new BreadcrumbItem { Url = $"{baseUrl}", Text="Home /", Icon="home" },
            new BreadcrumbItem { Text = "Middleware ", Url=$"{baseUrl}Environments/{environmentId}/Middlewares"}
        };
    }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        middlewareHeader = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<MiddlewareModel[]?>($"https://localhost:57031/api/Environments/{environmentId}/Middlewares");
    }
}
```

`

Comment: Resolved. In the model add a get method.
`public string IsEnable { get { return Active ? "Active" : "Disable";} }`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with Telerik.

The statement:

```
nameof(MiddlewareModel.Active ? "Active" : "Disable")
```

will give the same error in any context.

If you have an instance of Middleware class to work with then you'd use:

```
middlewareInstance.Active ? "Active" : "Disable"
```

to create the text `Active` or `Disable` based on the boolean value of Active property on middlewareInstance